# How to do training for Dialogflow Knowledge?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use [Dialogflow Knowledge](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/knowledge-connectors) but faced with a problem that I can't find how to improve recognition of my questions and link them to answers. In a training tab, I can link unrecognized questions only to intents, but not to Knowledge questions/answers.

How can I improve recognition of my questions for KnowledgeBase without converting it to intents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Knowledge is in Beta and does not support training feature as the regular intents. You may file a bug/enhancement for the same with the Dialogflow team.

As an alternative, you may use Knowledge base to generate regular intents by selecting the questions and converting it into intents as shown below. After the intent is created you may add your variations.

[image]

Comment: Without converting them to intents. Is there a way to manage 2 knowledge bases having very similar questions but different answers?

Comment: I haven't tried that. You can check and see. If it works, share the result here :)